# dataTable using Ajax function with millions of data

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a search page with datatable with millions of rows of data fetched from the database. 
I am stuck how to use the ajax data with deferRender and passing as datasets to the datatable.

See my datatable code below, then i have three queries:

**1. I would like to know how to pass the iterated and interval data to
   the datatable using callback???

2. How to pass the image column to
   pdf export? (the dataURL in the below code is not yeilding expected
   result)

3. And what all methods can be used to make the process faster?**

Datatable code:

```
$('#resultTable').DataTable( {                      
                destroy: true,  
                "autoWidth": false,    
                processing: true,
                "serverSide": true,             
                //"aaData": result,  // THIS IS WORKING FINE IF THE AJAX RESULT GIVEN DIRECTLY, BUT LOADING WILL TAKE MUCH TIME
                ajax: {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'search.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { durationFrom: durationFrom, durationTo: durationTo, type: type, color: color, city: city, number: number },      
                    success:function(result){ 
                        data = result;
                        var out = [];

                        for ( var i=0; i<data.length ; i++ ) {
                            out.push( [ data[i].id, data[i].eventtime, data[i].number, data[i].imageURL ] );
                        }

                        setTimeout( function () {
                            callback( {
                                draw: data.draw,
                                data: out,
                                recordsTotal: data.length,
                                recordsFiltered: data.length
                            } );
                        }, 50 );
                    }                       
                },
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "sTitle": "Id",
                    "mDataProp": "id",
                     "sWidth" : "50px" },                               
                    { "sTitle": "Date",
                    "mDataProp": "eventtime",
                     "sWidth" : "120px" },
                    {"sTitle": "Number",
                     "mDataProp": "number",
                     "sWidth" : "50px" },                  
                    {"sTitle": "Image",
                     "mDataProp": "imageURL",
                        "render": function(mDataProp, type, row) {
                            return '<img src="'+mDataProp+' " alt="No image available" />';
                            },
                     "sWidth" : "50px"
                    }
                ],
                //deferRender:    true,
                scrollY:        400,
                "bSortClasses": false,
                info: true,
                language: {
                        "zeroRecords": "No matching records found - Please search with different search criteria",
                            "emptyTable": "No data available in table",
                        "infoEmpty": "No entries to show",
                            "info": "Records _START_ to _END_ of _MAX_",
                        "loadingRecords": "Loading...",
                        "Processing":  "<img src='images/loader.gif' alt='Processing... Please wait...'>",
                        "LoadingRecords": 'Loading...',
                        "search":         "Search:",
                        "paginate": {
                            "first":      "First",
                            "last":       "Last",
                            "next":       "Next",
                            "previous":   "Previous"
                        },
                    },
                aaSorting : [[0, 'desc']],
                "pagingType": "input",  
                "pageLength": 100,
                "lengthMenu": [[100, 500, 1000, 10000], [100, 500, 1000, 10000]],
                dom: 'Blfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'copy',
                    {
                        extend: 'csv',
                        title: myFileName
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'excelHtml5', 
                        title: myFileName
                    },
                     'print' , 
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5', 
                        title: myFileName  ,
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                            stripHtml: false
                        },
                        customize: function (doc) {

                            for (var i=1;i<doc.content[1].table.body.length;i++) {

                                var imageMarkUp = doc.content[1].table.body[i][4].text;
                                var srcImg = $(imageMarkUp).attr('src');


                                var img = new Image,
                                    canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
                                    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
                                    src = srcImg; 

                                img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

                                img.onload = function() {
                                    canvas.width = img.width;
                                    canvas.height = img.height;
                                    ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
                                    localStorage.setItem( "savedImageData", canvas.toDataURL("image/png") );
                                }
                                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");                                            
//NOT WORKING Correctly

                                if (doc.content[1].table.body[i][4].text == img.src) {
                                    delete doc.content[1].table.body[i][4].text;
                                    doc.content[1].table.body[i][4].image = 'img';
                                }
                            }

                            doc.content.splice(4, 0, {
                                margin: [0, 0, 0, 12],
                                alignment: 'center',
                                image: dataURL
                            });
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
```

Comment: Add LIMIT to your query? And for your image loading, did you add base64 encoding in the image scr tag(if the data is base64string).

Comment: @Lucky: my requirement is to show without limit.
Regarding the image, i tried to convert to base64, but no avail, can you lighten me how could it be used?

Comment: Well you can't show the 1million records at the same time. So adding limit is a good practice and it also increase the load time(performance) and you can use ajax to show any number of records without any slowing down. If the image you are trying to use in src tag is a base64 string you can change it to `return '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'+mDataProp+' " />';` so that the browser can render it for you through Data URI. If it is simply an URL ignore the conversion. Look into what the browser renders itself in the image src tag. That will help you solve it.

Comment: Look into https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html & https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/defer_render.html

Comment: sorry, by no limit i meant "with limit but might have one million rows', may be if user is fetching the data of a month it might count near one million.
Also for the ajax, am using it now, but how to use the ajax with serverside processing looking at the above code?

For the image, let me try.

Thank you for your comments.